# Implementation of Huffman Coding

Tags: c++, c++17

This is an implementation of Huffman Coding that works on ASCII values. I simplified `main` to show an example of user input to the program. I only removed handling of non-printable ASCII characters, as that is not something I need reviewed. Initially, I tried to use `std::priority_queue<std::unique_ptr<node>>`, but you cannot easily remove these pointers due to `std::priority_queue::top` returning a const reference, so I had to use `std::shared_ptr`. More or less, I just want to know if there are any glaring issue with how I used the standard library or guideline violations.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>
#include <optional>
#include <sstream>

/// node
/// node in huffman tree
struct node {
    node(char c, int freq, std::shared_ptr<node> left, std::shared_ptr<node> right)
        : c {c}
        , freq {freq}
        , left {std::move(left)}
        , right {std::move(right)}
    {}
    node(int freq, std::shared_ptr<node> left, std::shared_ptr<node> right)
        : freq {freq}
        , left {std::move(left)}
        , right {std::move(right)}
    {}

    std::optional<char> c;
    int freq;
    std::shared_ptr<node> left;
    std::shared_ptr<node> right;
};

/// build_huffman_codings
/// traverses a huffman tree and finds encodings for all characters
/// \param root root of huffman tree or subtree
/// \param accumulator prefix of huffman code gathered before root
/// \param codings mapping of character to its final encoding
void build_huffman_codings(const std::shared_ptr<node>& root,
                           std::map<char, std::string>& codings,
                           std::string accumulator = "") {
    // leaf node adds to codings
    if (!root->left && !root->right) {
        codings[root->c.value()] = accumulator;
        return;
    }

    // left branch
    if (root->left) {
        build_huffman_codings(root->left, codings, accumulator + "0");
    }

    // right branch
    if (root->right) {
        build_huffman_codings(root->right, codings, accumulator + "1");
    }
}

/// huffman
/// compute huffman codings for given frequencies of characters
/// \param freq mapping of character and frequencies
/// \return mapping of character to a binary representation
std::map<char, std::string> huffman(const std::map<char, int>& freq) {
    // pre-allocate nodes
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>> nodes;
    for (const auto& pair : freq) {
        nodes.emplace_back(std::make_shared<node>(pair.first, pair.second, nullptr, nullptr));
    }

    // compare freq of node pointers
    auto compare_greater = [] (const auto& p1, const auto& p2) {
        return p1->freq > p2->freq;
    };
    // priority queue holds nodes in increasing order by frequency
    std::priority_queue<std::shared_ptr<node>,
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<node>>,
        decltype(compare_greater)>
        queue {compare_greater, std::move(nodes)};

    const std::size_t size = queue.size();

    // repeat size - 1 times
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i < size; ++i) {
        // remove first two nodes
        std::shared_ptr<node> x = queue.top();
        queue.pop();
        std::shared_ptr<node> y = queue.top();
        queue.pop();
        // add new node
        queue.emplace(std::make_shared<node>(x->freq + y->freq, x, y));
    }

    std::map<char, std::string> codings;
    build_huffman_codings(queue.top(), codings);
    return codings;
}

int main() {
    // store character with its frequency
    std::map<char, int> frequencies;

    // example user input - real implementation handles non-printable ascii
    std::stringstream freq_txt {
        "a 5\n"
        "b 25\n"
        "c 7\n"
        "d 15\n"
        "e 4\n"
        "f 12\n"
    };

    char c;
    int f;

    while (freq_txt) {
        freq_txt >> c;
        freq_txt >> f;
        frequencies[c] = f;
    }

    // huffman code table
    const auto codings = huffman(frequencies);

    for (const auto& pair : codings) {
        std::cout << pair.first << ' ' << pair.second << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance, I see a a lot of good usage of the standard library. So, the remarks I have are rather small:

- in huffman(), you create a vector `nodes`, as you know exactly the amount of elements to store into it, I would reserve it. This reduces memory usage slightly and improves performance. (`nodes.reserve(freq.size())`)
- In the same function, you don't seem to have handling for `size == 0`, most likely because of the simplification?
- a small optimization in the for-loop, you can use `std::move()` on `x` and `y`.
- In build_huffman_condings, you have `std::string accumulator =""`. It's better to write `= std::string{}`  as this doesn't require `strlen` to be called.

On the more high level, I am wondering about the used datastructures, especially `std::map`. I know `std::unordered_map` ain't an ideal hash-map, though, it does perform better than `std::map` if you don't need ordering. I don't see in your code that need, hence I would recommend replacing it. (You can also use abseil ... for a better implementation, or as the values are small, boosts flat_map)

In short, your usage of the standard library looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I used map over unordered_map because my calling code needed to output the table with ascii values in order.

Comment: Even than, if you know the characters, depending on the length of the text, it might be beneficial to use hash_map and at the end loop over all characters and locate. Though that all depends on the use cases.

Comment: Since `queue.top()` returns a `const shared_ptr&` - and even if I made `x` and `y` const, should I still use `move` on them? I'm getting warnings to not move const variables. I'm assuming it will handle the reference counts correctly and the warning may not apply in this situation.

Comment: You indeed make a copy of the shared_ptr when creating variable x, which is needed. However, when passing it along to the new node, you could move it.